# Is it possable to send keydown event and key up event?

Tags: lua, keypress, roblox, keyevent, luau

is there a way to send a key down and key up event in Lua? Is it possible? (This is my first time asking a question here, I'm so nervous '~')

I want it to help you auto-press the key without you touching anything, I am making a game in which you can press "E" to do stuff such as open door, enter car etc. and I want to make a script to troll player, and make him spam "E" (But not him pressing) and keep enter and jump out of car or opening and closing doors or else.

IMPORTANT: What I want isn't detecting key down up or press, what I want is to SEND a event to key down, up and press.

Comment: What game engine are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can't really force any players and do keypress from their client. You can detect them but not simulate them.

You can make a gui which would disappear when you press key or the gui stays on the screen and the player can't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force a keypress input from their client, but what you can do is assign the same function to a different event for example,

```lua
local button = script.Parent

button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
--your function here--
end

--different event here--:Connect(function()
--your function here--
end
```

so basically run the same function with a different event, because you cannot force input from the client

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do a send key down script for LuaU:

```
local vim = game:GetService('VirtualInputManager')
function Click(key, HT, cd)
    vim:SendKeyEvent(true, key, false, game)
    task.wait(HT)
    vim:SendKeyEvent(false, key, false, game)
    task.wait(cd)
end

Click(Enum.KeyCode.E, 0.1) -- Change whatever you want
```